# Authorize.net payment gateway endpoint url for joomla4

Tags: authorize.net, joomla4

currently, I am trying to implement the Authoroze.net payment gateway in my Joomla 4 project. I am using webhook notifications for payment transactions.

The problem I am facing is that the Authorize.net endpoint URL cannot contain any white space or special characters. Only dots, hyphens, underscores, forward-slash, numbers, and letters are allowed. But for the implementation I want the URL to be like this https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=payment.OnNotify
How can I achieve this using Joomla Api or the SEF route in Joomla 4?
Thanks in advance.